# Unable to instantiate driver object

Tags: java, spring, spring-test

I have written a spring Test integration setup to run selenium tests.Am unable to instantiate driver object using spring

Am new to Spring. Please let me know where am doing wrong.

Am trying to invoke selenium driver object so that i can use it in my test classes

//This class to create new driver object

DriverFactory

```
@Configuration
public class DriverFactory {

    public DriverFactory() {
    }

    @Bean
    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        ChromeDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        return new ChromeDriver();
    }
}
```

//This class to perform component scan

TestCoreConfiguration

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.cdm" })
public class TestCoreConfiguration {
    public TestCoreConfiguration() {
    }
}
```

// This class to start driver

CoreBaseTest

```
@ContextConfiguration(
    classes = {TestCoreConfiguration.class,DriverFactory.class}
)

public class CoreBaseTest  extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests{

    @Autowired(required = true )
    public WebDriver cs;

    public CoreBaseTest() {
        System.out.println(cs +"&&&&&&&&&&&&&&");
        cs.get("https://www.google.com");
    }

}
```

The driver object should be invoked

//This class to run actual tests

SanityTest

```
public class SanityTest extends CoreBaseTest{

@Test
public void sanityTest() {
}
}
```

Exception

```
 Cannot instantiate class com.cdm.Login.SanityTest
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:30)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:423)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:336)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:190)
    at org.testng.TestClass.getInstances(TestClass.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestClass.initTestClassesAndInstances(TestClass.java:81)
    at org.testng.TestClass.init(TestClass.java:73)
    at org.testng.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:38)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:389)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:271)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:241)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:192)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:33)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:66)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:713)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:260)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1295)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1273)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1128)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:24)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.cdm.core.CoreBaseTest.<init>(CoreBaseTest.java:23)
    at com.cdm.Login.SanityTest.<init>(SanityTest.java:7)
    ... 30 more
```

Comment: Did your SanityTest class not get posted right?  It has an extra curly in it and doesn't contain any code?  That's where the error is coming from, so it would be good to make sure that class is correctly represented.

Comment: yeah, But lets just for now, I need cs to be initialized in CoreBaseTest class constructor

Comment: Mostly saying that with a typo in there, readers wonder if there was supposed to be more there.

Comment: What would cause all of the Spring wiring to occur before your test runs?  You don't show any configuration structure around your test class.  The stack trace does not show that TestNG is doing anything Spring-specific (although maybe it woudn't anyway).  Are you using the "spring test runner" for NG?  If your test were to be run without any Spring support, of course you're going to get a NPE, because nothing will have been run to wire up your beans.  Just subclassing AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests isn't enough, I believe.